# What does conditional probability mean in case of two party system where no-signalling holds?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

**Background to the problem**:
I have two parties (  spatially separated ) $A$ and $B$ each having a set of measurements $M_A$ and $M_B$ respectively, and set of outcomes $m_A$ and $m_B$ respectively. Let $x \in M_A,y \in M_B, a\in m_a,b \in m_B$. $\lambda$ denotes the [local hidden variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_hidden_variable_theory) , then 
$$P(a,b|x,y)=\int \rho(\lambda)P(a|x,\lambda)P(b|y,\lambda)d \lambda...(1)$$
here $\rho(\lambda)$ is a probability distribution.
The above is obtained using  no-signalling principle $$P(a|x,y,\lambda)=P(a|x,\lambda)...(2)$$ that is $B$'s choice of measurement does not affect probability distribution for $A$ ( similarly $P(b|x,y,\lambda)=P(b|y,\lambda)$ ).

**My doubt**:
In equation $(2)$ from whose perspective is $P(a|x,y,\lambda)$ written ? I mean when I am writing this conditional probability does it mean that  I know $y$ has occurred or is it that I don't know $y$ has occurred but it has occurred ( latter one seems to be from $A$'s perspective ). I am sorry for not being clear enough and for such trivial doubt but I am confused as in this there are two observers rather than one.

Comment: $P(a|x,y,\lambda)$ is defined as the probability of $a$ given the occurence of $x,y,\lambda$. So $P(a,b|x,y)$ is the probability of the pair $a,b$ to occure when you $x,y$ has occured (or you know it will occur, or you assume it has occured).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional probability talks about things that have happened, so it's an objective reality (ignoring the questions of the objective reality's existence). It's unimportant if you know it's happened or not.

This of course changes a bit in experimental reality, where you (presumably) order your events $a$ based on your knowledge of the preconditions $x,y,\lambda$. Unless you take steps to remove wrong events (e.g. events where you thought $x,y,\lambda$ happened, but it didn't) the difference between the objective reality of occurences and your guessed occurences is an error.

Of course, you might also adapt $a$ to mean "I thought $a$ happened", but that's not really what most situation in which I've seen such formal questions asked mean.

TL;DR: $P(a|x,y,\lambda)$ is when it really happened.